# how retrieve data from checkedlistbox selected and show data in datagrideview?

Tags: c#, sql

I use these code to  retrieve data from checkedlistbox selected and show data  in datagrideview

problem query retrieve data one checkedlistbox selected not multi checkedlistbox selected I want to retrieve data in datagrideview with multi checkedlistbox selected

```
string s = "";
int x;
for (x = 0; x <= checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count - 1; x++)
{

    s = "'" + checkedListBox1.CheckedItems[x].ToString() + "',";

}
s = s.Substring(0, s.Length - 1);




con = new SqlConnection(cs.DBConn);
con.Open();


cmd = new SqlCommand("select id,'',raqam,name_sender,country1,country2,tel1,tel2,title,detalis,n_number,price,ship,total,name from pos where country2 IN("+s+") order by id asc ", con);

rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

bunifuCustomDataGrid1.Rows.Clear();
while (rdr.Read() == true)
{


    bunifuCustomDataGrid1.Rows.Add(rdr[0], rdr[1], rdr[2], rdr[3], rdr[4], rdr[5], rdr[6], rdr[7], rdr[8], rdr[9], rdr[10], rdr[11], rdr[12], rdr[13], rdr[14]);
    bunifuCustomDataGrid1.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>().Last().Selected = true;
    bunifuCustomDataGrid1.CurrentCell = bunifuCustomDataGrid1.Rows[bunifuCustomDataGrid1.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[1];

}
con.Close();
```